# Thin server auto restart script

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, azure, configuration, thin

I am a newbie on ubuntu and I am facing a issue on azure wherein the virtual machine automatically restarts because  of maintenance from microsoft.

Because of this my application is going down.
Also there is no confirmation from their(windows) side as to when the restart/system updates will take place.

Even If I start Thin Server how do I keep it open for a specific port ie for port 3000,3001,3002,3003.or so on..Please let me know.

I have gone through various blogs and have made changes in `init.d` to make the thin server start automatically during restart.

```
user: root
group: webuser
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
socket: tmp/sockets/thin.sock
chdir: webuser/app
tag: hey aux
```

I have tried the above but failed in it.

The below is my `etc/init.d thin` file:-

```
# Do NOT "set -e"

DAEMON=/usr/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

run_action() {
        ACTION="$1"

    if [ -x /usr/bin/ruby1.8 ]; then
        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 $DAEMON $ACTION --all /etc/thin1.8
    fi

    if [ -x /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 ]; then
        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 $DAEMON $ACTION --all /etc/thin1.9.1
    fi

}

case "$1" in
  start)
    run_action start
    ;;
  stop)
    run_action stop
    ;;
  restart|force-reload|reload)
    run_action restart
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

I dont know if the script is right or wrong.But the code does not seem to work.
Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you post your `init.d` script?

Comment: @Ash I have added the above configuration file called thin in etc/init.d folder.Let me knoe for any changes if necessary.Thanks

Comment: @Ash,,Is the code written above proper.Please let me know.Am stuck on it

Comment: @ravikanth Can you please help me with this..Went through your blogs on powershell and I think you can help me with this.

Comment: I think this question is on topic, but you'd probably have better luck with server maintenance questions at the SE site about servers, http://serverfault.com

Comment: @kevin..thanks a lot will do so

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use [this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sorah/1409781/raw/bd4f183aed3b7a11cf90b533c323240e3f35b55a/thin) for thin. From my experience though, it's better to use [Foreman](https://rubygems.org/gems/foreman) along with [upstart](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#UPSTART-EXPORT) to manage starting applications on boot. Works better and it's easier to configure.

Other than that, I'm not sure I understood your stack: You're deploying a ruby web application, on a Ubuntu VM running on a Windows 2012 server, on Azure?

Comment: Thanks for the help..Will try out the following.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can be done via systemd "Template unit files".

1. Define unit: `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mca-thin@.service`

```ini
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
# Notice "+-" or "+" command prefixes. They defines privileges and tolerance.
# See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines 
ExecStartPre=+-/usr/bin/mkdir /var/run/thin
ExecStartPre=+-/usr/bin/mkdir /var/log/thin
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/chown ec2-user:ec2-user /var/run/thin
# Notice placeholder "%i" It is used when running service from template.
# See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers
ExecStart=/usr/bin/thin start --chdir="/opt/mca/redmine" --address=0.0.0.0 --port=640%i --socket="/var/run/thin/redmine.%i.sock" --environment="production" --max-conns=1024 --max-persistent-conns=100 --threadpool-size=20 --timeout=30
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=truncate:/var/log/thin/stdout.%i.log
StandardError=truncate:/var/log/thin/stderr.%i.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Reload daemon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Check service status: `sudo systemctl status mca-thin@{1..2}`
4. Verify that it works as expected: `sudo systemctl start mca-thin@1` then `sudo systemctl stop mca-thin@1`
5. Enable service `sudo systemctl enable mca-thin@{1..2}`

Now you have a system services which will autostart on system start. Will also restart on failure. Services launched from such template will operate on ports range 6401....640**N** (set via `--port=640%i` template argument). Services sharing a Unix socket (set via `--socket="/var/run/thin/redmine.%i.sock"` template argument). Thus should not be a problem to hook them into nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `chkconfig`.
Check if the `thin` is `on` with the command:

```
chkconfig | grep thin
```

And if is not (maybe in your case) add it with:

```
chkconfig thin on
```

Comment: Ok will check it out @christos

Comment: I am getting chkconfig is not available (package)and it is not available

Comment: Check out [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Christos..I have gone through it..installed sysv-rc-conf however it is not working

Comment: @Christos..Also how do I set the port of the application I am running for so that it will go up as soon as it is restarted